# Power BI single data source multiple tables

Tags: powerbi, jira-rest-api

I am making a Power BI dashboard (via Power BI Desktop) for my team to show some key metrics of our project board. The data source is a JSON data from the JIRA REST API, and within the data contains everything that I need:

```
{
    ...
    "issues": [
        ...
        "fields": {
            ...
            "worklog": {
                ...
                "worklogs": [
                    ...
                ]
            }
        },
        "changelog": {
            ...
            "histories": [
                ...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

From it, I would like to have multiple tables transformed from the same data source, e.g. one for all the issues, and another one for the worklog. Since the worklog is scattered at the issue level, I would like to transform it so that it is just worklog, but without attempting to call the HTTP GET again.

I have yet to find any resource talking about this operation. Am I on the right track considering single data source and multiple table, and if this is the right track, could anyone please point to any resource demonstrating this capability?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference queries. That way you can have multiple queries building on top of another existing query (issues and work log in your case). I believe Power BI is clever enough to refresh the original data source only once when refreshing a report.

[image: Reference a table in Power BI Desktop]

Comment: I tried and it works beautifully. Thank you very much!